# How to custom parameterize ADF copy activity settings using arm-template-parameters-definition.json file?

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-resource-manager, azure-data-factory

I have the following Pipeline. There is an If Activity and in that there is a Copy Activity. I want to parameterize **Data integration unit** and **Degree of copy parallelism** settings:

[image: Pipeline]

I have added following code in my arm-template-parameters-definition.json file:

[image: arm-template-parameters-definition.json file]

But still, these 2 properties are not getting parameterized. Help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Hi Bilal Shafqat  Can you add it to arm-template-parameters-definition.json based on part of the json code I provided?

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you can declare two parameters or variables in ADF UI.
   [image]
2. In Copy activity setting, you can set click `Edit`.
   [image]
   Then add dynamic content and select your parameters.
   [image]
3. Then you can click `Save as template` to export ARM template.
   [image]
4. The part of ARM template is as follows:

```json
    "typeProperties":{
        "source":{"type":"DelimitedTextSource",
        "storeSettings":{
            ...
            "parallelCopies":{"value":"@pipeline().parameters.DegreeParam","type":"Expression"},
            "dataIntegrationUnits":{"value":"@pipeline().parameters.DiuParam","type":"Expression"},
            ...
            "parameters":{"DiuParam":{"type":"int","defaultValue":2},"DegreeParam":{"type":"int","defaultValue":2}},
```

Comment: This is a valid solution. But I wanted to directly parameterize DIU and Copy Parallelism to use them in CI CD.

Comment: Hi @Bilal Shafqat. Have you found a solution now?